# Node app memory usage increasing with time

Tags: node.js, performance, memory-leaks, mean-stack, pm2

I am running the MEAN application which has client and server both separate folders and I am using pm2 for this. When I do pm2 restart all then application working fine and using less memory but after some time it's getting increased and slowing the application.
I have attached 2 screenshots of 10 hrs interval to explain my problem.

[Check Image: After restarting PM2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUalk.jpg)

[Check Image: After 10 hrs of running application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDpu3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be said without looking at your code. It looks like you must be storing data in memory which gets bigger over time. Please check if you can clear all such variables and keep there size minimum.

Comment: Can i share the app.js file with you?

Comment: Yes, please share

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, a more efficient code that avoids redundant vars would be the best solution but that is easier said than done, if you are using PM2 you can use `max_memory_restart` and give it a memory limit for the application. Doing so will make your app restart every time it goes over and thus, keeps your systems clear.

You can enable this by editing your `ecosystem.config.js`

You can read it more about it on their docs: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/